# AJAX PHP Sending and getting back text after few operations on the fly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send on the fly textarea's text into PHP variable, do a few operations on the text in PHP and get back result also on the fly.

For now I have working getting back PHP variable on the fly, but I don't know how to enchance this to sending textarea's text on the fly into PHP before.

I've this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval('get_counter()', 500);
    });
    function get_counter()
    {
        $('.result').load('2.php');
    }
</script>
<div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this 2.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameter to your backend via the second argument in the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function if the argument is passed as an object a POST request is made.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(get_counter, 500);
    });
    function get_counter()
    {
        $('.result').load('2.php',{text:$('textarea').val()});
    }
</script>
```